# I am curious about the ubuntu phone?

Tags: phone

I have a galaxy s 5 and want to know if putting ubuntu phone on it if it will brick or work? If it bricks I can all ways upgrade to the note 4, which leads me to my next question. Would it work on the note 4? I think the desktop on the note 4 would be pretty awesome to have. I love that you guys are trying to put pc power on phones. Keep it up. Please.

Answer (score 0):

Right now all versions of Ubuntu's phone OS are try at your own risk. You can learn more at the links below:

[Ubuntu Phone](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone) - Official Page

[Ubuntu On Air](http://ubuntuonair.com/) - Developer live streaming - Ubuntu Phone is almost always a topic